# connect a circuit output to a transformer

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, buffer

Helo

I have a sine wave oscillator, i want its output to drive a transformer. 
When i connect a voltage source to the transformer i get the amplification desired
[image]
 but when i connect it to the circuit output and remove the source, the transformer output drops to milivolts.the voltage source and the circuit have the same amplitudes.

i tried to use an opamp as a buffer but i don't know which or how to choose it, so i tried several different ones(only on SPICE not in the lab) and the output reaches the high voltages but it looks like that, [image]

is an opamp is the solution for this problem ?
if so, what kind of opamp should i look for(specs)
any other suggestions and tips will be much appericiated.

Thanks

Comment: If you do use an op-amp you want one with a low output impedance. Maybe an audio power amplifier would be a better choice?

Comment: I don't see any power connected to the op-amp you have added. Also, what does the output of the "oscillator" look like when it is unloaded?

Comment: U5 is unpowered. R10 is open, meaning no current can flow in the secondary. Try powering U5 and connecting that open side of R10 to ground.

Answer (score 1):

Things wrong: -

- The LT1007 needs some power rails
- The pulse generator on the left will contravene the input common-mode range of the device. What is this pulse generator for?

Things to consider: -

- Input range for LT1007 (when actually powered) does not include the negative rail.

Comment: " it has total positive feedback at DC " - Sorry, no. U1 is an inverter, and U2-U4 are followers, so the loop will close properly at DC.  Also, I believe that the pulse generator a keying mechanism. When at 0 volts it will indeed kill the oscillation by violating common mode/saturation limits, but at 6 will provide a sort of virtual ground to allow oscillation.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast good spot - I shall remove that stupidity. Yes, regards the pulse generator I agree.

Comment: [link] (https://imagebin.ca/v/35EZiAqcdEvF) link for waveforms. the sine wave at the transformer output gets distorted, how should  i choose the opamp to get less distortion ? what about using a capacitor in the negetive feedback loop ?(it maintains the sine wave form but attenuates the HPF output to milivolts, tried it with different capacitance values)  @WhatRoughBeast any suggestions ? thanks for help

Comment: U5 in that image requires positive AND negative supplies to force a proper AC voltage across the transformer primary. You might also find that a simple op-amp isn't man-enough to drive it as well. The transformer primary seems to have an inductance value of 4.6 mH and, at 1 kHz this is an impedance of only 29 ohms. So it's too low for this sort of op-amp.

Comment: You might also consider adding a push pull stage like this: http://www.linear.com/solutions/5631